# How to maintain a stable DC current in case of intermittent disconnections

Tags: dc, inverter, led-strip, led-driver

Aplogies if the question sounds very basic.
I have a set of LED strips which are powered by a 12v 5A LED driver (which is plugged to my wall socket 220V AC).

As the intermidiate connection between the LED strips and DC power has some mechanical components, there is a frequent disconnection between the two for a second or so every minute (unfortunately the mechanical bits is quiet old and cannot be replaced). This results in  the LED flickering.

Can someone provide me any insights on any particular circuit arrangement I can use to collect and disperse the current during these disconnections ?
(Some kind of collector arrangement) ??

Comment: Hold steady then glue with epoxy

Comment: You need to estimate how much power everything consumes, I have actually no idea if there is some supercap that can store enough energy for a second of that kind of consumption, but it takes only a little math. I assume you don't run it at full 12*5=60W, but even if so, this number is your starting point. You need to provide 60W for 2 seconds without losing too much voltage in that cap (never worked with supercaps or whatever they're called, so no idea how realistic it is). Estimate how much energy you need to store. All from basic capacitor formula. See if it's realistic numbers

Comment: @Tony : Nice one :)

Comment: @Ilya : Thanks for the suggestion. Let me research a bit on supercaps too. I have never herd of them as well.  Speaking of which can somenkind of battery arrangement work ? I.e. powering the LED by a battery pack and charging it simultaneously with the intermittent current ? Issue i see is will the charging circuit last in such conditions (just a thought)

Comment: You cannot overcome loss of power without a massive surge and damage on reconnection from a low ESR storage

Comment: You are looking for undervoltage protection.  Usually this is done with capacitors, but at these power levels, there'll be BIG inrush current when the connection is re-made.  There are circuits that charge caps in parallel and then discharge them in series when the load side V drops, but I don't know how well it scales.

Comment: Switchmode Power Supply Handbook by Keith Billings and Taylor Morey has a section on undervoltage protection.  It's done at the DC level, not the AC side.

Comment: Wow.. thank you everyone for the feedback and comments. As Aaron and Tony mentioned, It seems like there is no quick solution for this problem. Looking at the scenario I decided to go via the battery route and power the LEDs using battery while charging the same using the regular charger with protection. This video gave provide good insights https://youtu.be/Rdzv9Y1zHC0. Thank you again for the assistance. I'll continue digging the super caps route for a more permanent solution and wil update my progress here.

Answer (score 0):

Using Super caps seem to be a vaiable answer to the issue but more investigation will be required. As of now I changed the design slightly and now will try powering the LED using an rechargable battery with the intermittent current used to charge it. (Reference video : https://youtu.be/Rdzv9Y1zHC0)